# How can I specify multiple operating points?

Tags: openmdao

Say I have a code where I can set a certain parameter, alpha.
How would I set up the program so I can optimise across multiple values of alpha, or optimise at one while obeying constraints on another?

Comment: in order to get more complete answers, please post some code samples with your questions. Without those, we're limited to giving very vauge answers. A little more effort put into asking detailed and well posed questions will make it much easier for us to give good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, you would just defined you alpha input to be a vector instead of a scalar. Then you can add one or more index of that array as a design/variable. You can also use the [EqConstraintComp](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/building_blocks/components/eq_constraint_comp.html) to set some indices equal to specific values.